# TypeError: Unserializable object for ipyaggrid table cell renderer

Tags: python-3.x

I use "ipyaggrid" lib. I want to convert all price values to float format with 2 decimal places and add a prefix £. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it, that I'm getting an error `TypeError: Unserializable object <function currency_renderer at 0x0000026B9F46AB60> of type <class 'function'>`. Thanks for any help

```
def currency_renderer(params):
    formatted_value = "£{:.2f}".format(float(params.value))
    return formatted_value


def create_aggrid(df):
    currency_columns = ['size', 'pnl', 'commission']
    column_defs = [
        {
            'headerName': column,
            'field': column,
            'cellRenderer': currency_renderer if column in currency_columns else None
        }
        for column in df.columns
    ]

    grid_options = {
        'columnDefs' : column_defs,
        'defaultColDef': {'sortable': 'true', 'filter': 'true', 'resizable': 'true'},
    }

    ag_grid = grid.Grid(grid_data=df,
            export_mode="buttons",
            columns_fit='auto',
            grid_options=grid_options,
            theme='ag-theme-balham',
            keep_multiindex=False,
            center=True)
    
    return ag_grid
```